# How to cut text using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, woocommerce

How to cut ".00" from class ".woocommerce-Price-amount" using javascript. There must be a space at the end of the amount.

```html
<div class="elementor-shortcode">
  Free shipping from 
    <span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <bdi>100,00&nbsp;
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">USD</span>           </bdi>
    </span>.
</div>
```

Comment: `Number.parseFloat('100,00')` will it work?

Comment: better to do it before its displayed, have you seen this: https://www.dhirenpatel.me/remove-decimals-product-prices-woocommerce/

Comment: I'm confused. I can't see any .00 after the class `woocommerce-Price-amount ...`

Comment: Mr. Jo - <span> contains this text and this class

Comment: Lawerence Cherone - Thanks for your advice. I want to use 2 decimals on a single product page. I just want to use the cuted amount in the bar at the top of the page so I can't change the woocommerce settings

Comment: girish - Can you put the full code on https://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0):

You can use split for this try this one,

```
var word = Hi 00;
word.split("00");
```

Comment: Can you put the full code on https://jsfiddle.net/?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like that?

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("bdi");
  var splittedStr = x[0].innerHTML.replace(',00', '');
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = splittedStr;
}
```

```html
<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">
      <bdi>100,00&nbsp;
        <span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">USD</span>
        </bdi>
    </span>
    
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
```